# Solr query works in browser but not using RestTemplate org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse

Tags: java, spring, solr, resttemplate, solr-query-syntax

I'm trying to run a solr query at the start of my tests to get a bunch of listings which I will then use in the test run.

If I make this request in Chrome I get the json response:

> *MYAPIDOMAIN*/solr/listings/select?q=category:commercial+AND+property_type:office&fl=listing_id,listing_status&group=true&group.main=true&group.field=listing_status&group.limit=1&rows=100&wt=json&indent=on

In the tests I am using the Spring RestTemplate to make the call then I parse the JSON response, it works for some of my queries but for this one I just get an error back:

```
 "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":7,
    "params":{
      "q":"category:commercial%2BAND%2Bproperty_type:office",
      "group.main":"true",
      "indent":"on",
      "fl":"listing_id,listing_status",
      "group.limit":"1",
      "rows":"100",
      "wt":"json",
      "group.field":"listing_status",
      "group":"true"}},
  "error":{
    "msg":"org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'category:commercial%2BAND%2Bproperty_type:office': Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 41.\nWas expecting one of:\n    <EOF> \n    <AND> ...\n    <OR> ...\n    <NOT> ...\n    \"+\" ...\n    \"-\" ...\n    <BAREOPER> ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    \"^\" ...\n    <QUOTED> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\n    <WILDTERM> ...\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"{\" ...\n    <LPARAMS> ...\n    <NUMBER> ...\n    ",
    "code":400}}
```

I don't know anything about solr queries I was just given them to use in the tests, obviously it's an encoding problem but I don't know where. I've tried using the URLEncoder, I've found some online url encoders but nothing seems to get this working.

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this? I have another 5 queries I need to make so I really need a fix.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same on my local and found the same error, it is due to the encoded value %2B -> + in your syntax. And it is breaking the parser.

So you could use the space instead of + which will change to %20. Then it should be working fine.